# Closing connection - InputStream

Tags: java, file, url, connection, inputstream

i need to check, if the file on adresse exists before I download it. It works fine until it reaches some not existing file. The try-catch block doesnt solve it well. When I open the connection (InputStream), it tries to download it, but fails and go to "catch". But it doesnt close it's self. Next time I call the method with the same IP, it crashes and sais - Too many connections on the same IP (2)

Summary:

until it reaches wrong adresse, it works fine

when it reaches wrong adresse, it goes to "catch", but doesnt close it's self and it cant be connected anymore

```
public boolean exists(String URLName) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    URL url = new URL(URLName);
    try {
        input = url.openStream();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        result = true;
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        input.close();
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've tried various procedures, but without some special trick it wont work. Please, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: As this is client code it should not fail or block just after one failed connection. Is this a case of many failed connections still in TIME_WAIT stage?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block to close my `InputStream` and refactor the code to use `URLConnection` instead.

Example:

```
public boolean exists(String URLName) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
    connection = new URL(URLName).openConnection();
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: good one.. i thought i would just go with telling rather then showing how to do it..

Comment: sure, its more then copying and pasting the people should do when they ask questions..

Comment: it doesnt work then... i still have too many connections there... it won't download next file

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Finally block and close your all connections in it... ??

Comment: i think it serves as a solution as well. isn't it?

Comment: when i try to close the connection when it's not opened, it thows nullpointerex...

Comment: It does, but an answer should be more descriptive and emphasis needs to be shown to your work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the new version of apache HttpClient http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html, with this code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
 GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url);
      try{
httpClient.executeMethod(get);


        return get.getResponseBodyAsString();


    } catch (HttpException clP_e) {

        throw new IOException(clP_e);

    } finally {

        get.releaseConnection();

    }
```

Comment: No, It doesn't for that you have to use: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/